# Clustering algorithms and Hausdorff distance

Tags: cluster-analysis, polygons, r-tree

I cant figure out this situation.
How the r tree can help to speed up finding close polygons using Hausdorff distance measure.
Tell me please how I can find close polygons for P4?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the minimum distance from P4 to other rectangles.

Prove that this distance is a lower bound for Hausdorff.

Which rectangles can thus contain an answer?

Comment: yes, but how to speed it up using R tree?  i want to reduce complexity from n^2 to logn, if i will search for closest polygons for all polygons

Comment: If the minimum distance of the bounding box of P1,P2,P3 to the bounding box of P4,P5,P6 is too large, you don't need to look at e.g. P1,P4, and that is how you get the speedup. It's called "pruning of search results". You can only get down to O(n log n) though for pairwise search, and only for small distance thresholds.

Comment: one more question: how we recognize that distance between {P1,P2,P3} polygon and {P4,P5,P6} is not too large? In first step we initialize eps, but eps is a minimum Hausdorff between exact polygon units, and not between sets of polygons. I'm using JTS Topology suite and it able to query only by boudary box.

Comment: Prove that the distance between the rectangles it is a lower bound of the Hausdorff fistance of the contents.